# Perl SOAP::Lite result only in debug?

Tags: xml, perl, soap, soap-client

I'm a little stuck. I use SOAP::Lite and it returns an empty result.

Using the debug-mode, I see that the request is successful.
Where is my error?

```
use Data::Dumper;
use Encode;
use SOAP::Lite;

my $user="username";
my $password="password";
my $ean = '1234567890123'
my $service_url='http://produktdaten.xxx.net/soapschemes/EAN.wsdl';

my $client = SOAP::Lite->service($service_url);  
$client->soapversion('1.2'); 
$client->envprefix('soap12');

my @headers = (
    SOAP::Header->name('PID')->value($user),
    SOAP::Header->name('password')->value($password) );

# make the call 
my $result = $client->getProductsByEAN($user,$password,$ean);

print Dumper($result);
```

$result prints out:

```
$VAR1 = '0';
```

When I turn on the debug mode

```
use SOAP::Lite +trace => 'debug';
```

, I get:

```
SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client::send_receive: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection: close
Date: Sun, 30 Jun 2013 11:27:26 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: nginx/1.4.0
Content-Length: 4447
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Client-Date: Sun, 30 Jun 2013 11:36:15 GMT
Client-Peer: x.x.x.x.x:80
Client-Response-Num: 1
Set-Cookie: xxx_CORE=344gb3h94nlmob7am9bmv3pv40; path=/
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.15

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="urn:xmethodsProductDataService" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:enc="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding"><env:Body><ns1:getProductsByEANResponse env:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">7{......AND SO ON...]
```

Can you tell me where what I'm missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? According to the `SOAP::Lite` docs, `service` is a method you call when you want to read the WSDL to create method stubs. The rest of your code, however, looks like you are trying to call a webservice directly. I guess, `SOAP::Lite` is confused.

Comment: I don't know anything about these libraries, but I notice the variable `@headers` is unused. Is that relevant?

Comment: I used "service" to load the wsdl-file (seeh here:http://guide.soaplite.com/#access%20with%20service%20description%20%28wsdl%29 ). 

The search method I use is: $client->getProductsByEAN.

Answer (score 0):

Recommended way is to create classes this way: [http://metacpan.org/pod/SOAP::WSDL::Manual](http://metacpan.org/pod/SOAP%3a%3aWSDL%3a%3aManual)

You could use [SOAP::WSDL](http://metacpan.org/pod/SOAP%3a%3aWSDL) to do this:

```
 my $soap = SOAP::WSDL->new(
    wsdl => 'http://produktdaten.xxx.net/soapschemes/EAN.wsdl',
 );



my $result = $soap->call('MyMethod', %data);
```